# Getting webpage not available errors when trying to run Routes example code with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Javascript newbie here..

I've trying to run the example code given in the [routes](https://www.npmjs.org/package/routes) documentation.

Code:

```
var Router = require('routes');
var router = new Router();

router.addRoute('/admin/*?', auth);
router.addRoute('/admin/users', adminUsers);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  var match = router.match(path);
  match.fn(req, res, match);
}).listen(1337)

// authenticate the user and pass them on to
// the next route, or respond with 403.
function auth(req, res, match) {
  if (checkUser(req)) {
    match = match.next();
    if (match) match.fn(req, res, match);
    return;
  }
  res.statusCode = 403;
  res.end()
}

// render the admin.users page
function adminUsers(req, res, match) {
  // send user list
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.end();
}
```

I can run this via `node app.js` and it starts up fine. However, when I hit `http://localhost:1337/admin` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'fn' of undefined
```

To make sure I wasn't doing something wrong in the server, I reset it back to the example Node app:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  .write("Hello world!");
  res.end();
}).listen(1337)
```

And this runs fine. I can hit `localhost` and see it print out hello world. So why am I getting a type error when I run the `routes` example code?

Comment: Um, maybe because `/admin` doesn't match `/admin/*`, hence doesn't match any rule? Have you tried to visit `/admin/` instead of `/admin`?

Comment: @Passerby Yes. `/admin`, `/admin/`, `/admin/adsf`. All result in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the path formats here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/routes#path-formats

Clearly, having used `router.addRoute('/admin/*?', auth);`, we cannot expect to get served at `localhost:1337/admin` or `localhost:1337/admin/`
To achieve this, just remove the `?`.

Use simply `router.addRoute('/admin/*', auth);` and you are good to go with `localhost:1337/admin/`. Though I still doubt that `localhost:1337/admin` will work. For that as the documentation says, we need to use `router.addRoute('/admin', auth);`